# object has no attribute error when trying to read from a file

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

Im trying to code something that replaces a string in a file with input from the user. I keep getting the error builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' What is causing this error? As far as I know the syntax should be correct. I'm still pretty new to Python though.

My code is:

```
import os


filename = input('Enter a filename: ')
old = input('Enter the old string to be replaced: ')
new = input('Enter the new string to replace the old string: ')

os.path.isfile(filename)

data = ''
open(filename, 'r')
data += filename.read().replace(old, new)
filename.close()

open(filename, 'w')
filename.write(data)
filename.close()
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a file handler. You can't use read method directly on filename.

For e.g

```
fh = open(filename, 'r')
data = fh.readlines()
```